# App crashes when request.results of CoreML sqeezeNet model is casted as [VNRectangleObservation]

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, apple-vision

I am using CoreML SqueezeNet Model to detect paper or rectangles from an image.

I have created model and request as per apple documentation.

```
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: squeezeNetModel.model)else {fatalError()}
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
     guard let rectangles = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else{ fatalError()}
}
```

Above code worked fine. But I want to detect paper and hence used [VNRectangleObservation] instead of [VNClassificationObservation].
This causes my app to crash. I don't find solution to this problem anywhere. The main reason I want to use [VNRecatangleObservation] is to capture detected image and draw red color overlay on detected image.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your app crashes is that `request.results` is an array of `VNClassificationObservation` objects. You cannot cast this into an array of `VNRectangleObservation` objects, since that is something completely different. It's like buying a bottle of milk from the store and trying to turn it into a coke by putting a Coca-Cola label on the bottle. It doesn't work.

If you want to detect *where* in the image the objects occur, you'll need to use a different model, like squeezeDet (with a D) or YOLO.

Comment: As per model , it returns [Any] as its results , hence I thought I could cast it.  Thank you for answering.